# Save all files in Visual Studio project as UTF-8

Tags: visual-studio, utf-8, character-encoding

I wonder if it's possible to save all files in a Visual Studio 2008 project into a specific character encoding. I got a solution with mixed encodings and I want to make them all the same (UTF-8 with signature).

I know how to save single files, but how about all files in a project?

Comment: You should know that RC compiler (as least untill Visual Studio 2008) does not supports UTF8 files - for these files you have to use UTF16.

Comment: Also, [`GlobalSuppressions.cs`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/33614568/1497596) is UTF-16.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Since you're already in Visual Studio, why not just simply write the code?

```cs
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"...").GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  string s = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
  File.WriteAllText (f.FullName, s, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Only three lines of code! I'm sure you can write this in less than a minute :-)

Comment: What about subdirectories, eg. the "Properties" subdir with lots of *.cs files?

Comment: The "SearchOption.AllDirectories" parameter is all that's necessary to include subdirectories. I've edited the code accordingly.

Comment: I have now tried it and it works great. The only thing I had to modify was to use Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)=Western European (Windows) as the second parameter to ReadAllText to preserve my swedish characters (åäö).

Comment: This solution is even better after VS2015 when you can run this snippet through here: **View -> Other Windows -> C# Interactive**

Answer (score 41):

This may be of some help.

> link removed due to original reference being defaced by spam site.

Short version: edit one file, select File -> Advanced Save Options. Instead of changing UTF-8 to Ascii, change it to UTF-8. *Edit: Make sure you select the option that says no byte-order-marker (BOM)*

Set code page & hit ok. It seems to persist just past the current file.

Comment: Change it to "Unicode (UTF-8 without signature)", otherwise it will add a BOM to the beginning of the file.

Comment: Agreed as well... somebody set up us the BOM.

Comment: If your file only contains 7-bit ASCII characters, or if any 8-bit ANSI character is not near the top, saving it as UTF-8 without BOM will open it in other editors (like VSCode) as ASCII or a local encoding (like ISO-8859-1, or windows-1252, to name a few). To enforce the encoding, you **must use the BOM** :).

Comment: Also, using UTF-8, there is no codepage...(Windows used CP65001 for UTF8 and CP1200 for UTF-16). Actual codepages are a thing of the past. Have a look at [this old, but still relevant, famous Joel Spolsky post](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/). And see this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing

Answer (score 12):

In case you need to do this in PowerShell, here is my little move:

```
Function Write-Utf8([string] $path, [string] $filter='*.*')
{
    [IO.SearchOption] $option = [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories;
    [String[]] $files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles((Get-Item $path).FullName, $filter, $option);
    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        "Writing $file...";
        [String]$s = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file);
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $s, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
    }
}
```

Comment: The file stays as UTF8-Signed in visual studio Advanced save options

Comment: Unicode characters are lost after execution. For example, Ü becomes � and © becomes �.

Comment: Be very careful with this code, because it'll destroy your .git directory too (as it just did for me).  I suggest changing the wildcard te `*.cs`.  Silly me for trusting the code snippet blindly.

Answer (score 8):

I would convert the files programmatically (outside VS), e.g. using a Python script:

```py
import glob, codecs

for f in glob.glob("*.py"):
    data = open("f", "rb").read()
    if data.startswith(codecs.BOM_UTF8):
        # Already UTF-8
        continue
    # else assume ANSI code page
    data = data.decode("mbcs")
    data = codecs.BOM_UTF8 + data.encode("utf-8")
    open("f", "wb").write(data)
```

This assumes all files not in "UTF-8 with signature" are in the ANSI code page - this is the same what VS 2008 apparently also assumes. If you know that some files have yet different encodings, you would have to specify what these encodings are.

Answer (score 6):

Using C#:
1) Create a new ConsoleApplication, then install [Mozilla Universal Charset Detector](https://nuget.org/packages/UDE.CSharp)
2) Run code:

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    const string targetEncoding = "utf-8";
    foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"<your project's path>").GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
    {
        var fileEnc = GetEncoding(f.FullName);
        if (fileEnc != null && !string.Equals(fileEnc, targetEncoding, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            var str = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding(fileEnc));
            File.WriteAllText(f.FullName, str, Encoding.GetEncoding(targetEncoding));
        }
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

private static string GetEncoding(string filename)
{
    using (var fs = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        var cdet = new Ude.CharsetDetector();
        cdet.Feed(fs);
        cdet.DataEnd();
        if (cdet.Charset != null)
            Console.WriteLine("Charset: {0}, confidence: {1} : " + filename, cdet.Charset, cdet.Confidence);
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Detection failed: " + filename);
        return cdet.Charset;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best solution nowadays is to add to your `.editorconfig` file in the `[*.cs]` (or whatever format you want) section:

`charset = utf-8`

For example, my `.editorconfig` begins with:

```
[*.cs]

charset = utf-8
```

You can also use `utf-8-bom` if you need to.

Next is to run the [dotnet format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-format) command in the folder with the solution file, it will do the job.

Done!

Comment: Should be marked as answer in 2023! Just tried in a solution with 3-4 different encodings, it solved it all beautifully.

Comment: I tried this with .cshtml files it did not work :/ any suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, @d0rf47, I only have a couple of .cshtml files, so I didn't have a problem with them. Looks like [it's a known issue](https://github.com/dotnet/format/issues/153), you can track it and boost with reactions/comments

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your solutions, this code has worked for me :

```vb
Dim s As String = ""
Dim direc As DirectoryInfo = New DirectoryInfo("Your Directory path")

For Each fi As FileInfo In direc.GetFiles("*.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    s = File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName, System.Text.Encoding.Default)
    File.WriteAllText(fi.FullName, s, System.Text.Encoding.Unicode)
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I have created a function to change encoding files written in asp.net. 
I searched a lot. And I also used some ideas and codes from this page. Thank you.

And here is the function.

```vb
  Function ChangeFileEncoding(pPathFolder As String, pExtension As String, pDirOption As IO.SearchOption) As Integer

    Dim Counter As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim reader As IO.StreamReader
    Dim gEnc As Text.Encoding
    Dim direc As IO.DirectoryInfo = New IO.DirectoryInfo(pPathFolder)
    For Each fi As IO.FileInfo In direc.GetFiles(pExtension, pDirOption)
        s = ""
        reader = New IO.StreamReader(fi.FullName, Text.Encoding.Default, True)
        s = reader.ReadToEnd
        gEnc = reader.CurrentEncoding
        reader.Close()

        If (gEnc.EncodingName <> Text.Encoding.UTF8.EncodingName) Then
            s = IO.File.ReadAllText(fi.FullName, gEnc)
            IO.File.WriteAllText(fi.FullName, s, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8)
            Counter += 1
            Response.Write("<br>Saved #" & Counter & ": " & fi.FullName & " - <i>Encoding was: " & gEnc.EncodingName & "</i>")
        End If
    Next

    Return Counter
End Function
```

It can placed in .aspx file and then called like:

```
ChangeFileEncoding("C:\temp\test", "*.ascx", IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
```

Answer (score 1):

if you are using TFS with VS :
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1yft8zkw(v=vs.100).aspx
Example :

```
tf checkout -r -type:utf-8 src/*.aspx
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid this type of error :

[image]

Use this following code :

```
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"....").GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                string s = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName, Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));
                File.WriteAllText(f.FullName, s, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
```

Encoding number 1252 is the default Windows encoding used by Visual Studio to save your files.

Answer (score 1):

## Convert from UTF-8-BOM to UTF-8

Building on [rasx's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1326157/5185376), here is a PowerShell function that assumes your current files are already encoded in UTF-8 (but maybe with BOM) and converts them to UTF-8 without BOM, therefore preserving existing Unicode characters.

```
Function Write-Utf8([string] $path, [string] $filter='*')
{
    [IO.SearchOption] $option = [IO.SearchOption]::AllDirectories;
    [String[]] $files = [IO.Directory]::GetFiles((Get-Item $path).FullName, $filter, $option);
    foreach($file in $files)
    {
        "Writing $file...";
        [String]$s = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($file, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8);
        [Text.Encoding]$e = New-Object -TypeName Text.UTF8Encoding -ArgumentList ($false);
        [IO.File]::WriteAllText($file, $s, $e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Experienced encoding problems after converting solution from VS2008 to VS2015. After conversion all project files was encoded in ANSI, but they contained UTF8 content and was recongnized as ANSI files in VS2015. Tried many conversion tactics, but worked only this solution.

```cs
 Encoding encoding = Encoding.Default;
 String original = String.Empty;
 foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(path).GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
 {
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(f.FullName, Encoding.Default))
    {
       original = sr.ReadToEnd();
       encoding = sr.CurrentEncoding;
       sr.Close();
    }
    if (encoding == Encoding.UTF8)
       continue;
    byte[] encBytes = encoding.GetBytes(original);
    byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(encoding, Encoding.UTF8, encBytes);
    var utf8Text = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(utf8Bytes);

    File.WriteAllText(f.FullName, utf8Text, Encoding.UTF8);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the item is removed  from the menu in Visual Studio 2017
You can still access the functionality through File-> Save As -> then clicking the down arrow on the Save button and clicking "Save With Encoding...".

You can also add it back to the File menu through Tools->Customize->Commands if you want to.

Answer (score 0):

set this new UTF8Encoding(true) in read and write

```
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Apps\ClRs\ClrsWeb").GetFiles("*.aspx.vb", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                string s = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName, new UTF8Encoding(true));
                File.WriteAllText(f.FullName, s,new UTF8Encoding(true));
            }
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm only offering this suggestion in case there's no way to automatically do this in Visual Studio (I'm not even sure this would work):

1. Create a class in your project named **足の不自由なハッキング** (or some other unicode text that will force Visual Studio to encode as UTF-8).
2. Add "using MyProject.**足の不自由なハッキング**;" to the top of each file.  You should be able to do it on everything by doing a global replace of "using System.Text;" with "using System.Text;using MyProject.**足の不自由なハッキング**;".
3. Save everything.  You may get a long string of "Do you want to save X.cs using UTF-8?" messages or something.

Comment: Duh, if you really want to make it stick just add a *comment* with those characters. At least it won't get deleted next time someone goes "Remove Unused Usings" in the Edit menu.

Comment: Add "using MyProject.足の不自由なハッキング;" to the top of each file. - I think the main reason for the question was, not to have to open each file separately.

Comment: This does not work for files with German Umlaut characters like äöüß. The file content will still be non-UTF.