# Pass UTF-8 arguments to PHP via Windows command prompt

Tags: php, unicode, command-prompt

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8");  // output as text file
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");   // output as HTML 
header("Accept-Charset: utf-8");
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');

$output_file = 'C:\\junk.txt';
$input = $argv[1];

file_put_contents($output_file, 'я ' . mb_detect_encoding($argv[1]) . ': ' . $argv[1]);
return;

?>
```

On the command prompt:

```
php C:\test.php я
```

The resulting file:

```
я ASCII: ?
```

I've tried changing the code page to 65001, that didn't help.  How in the world do I pass a unicode character to PHP from the command prompt?  It just assumes everything is ASCII.  I'm expecting it to print out:

```
я UTF-8: я
```

Comment: It night be unrelated to your problem but [mb_detect_encoding()](http://php.net/mb_detect_encoding) is normally not as useful as it seems. Good old [bin2hex()](http://php.net/bin2hex) tends to be a better diagnose tool for encoding issues.

Comment: I added `bin2hex($argv[1])` and it shows 3f.  It literally thinks it's a question mark...

Comment: I've been faced to this several times and I reached the conclusion that Windows command prompt simply does not support UTF-8 at all (no matter that a [65001 codepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing) exists). Let's wait and hopefully see other opinions.