# Copying directories with special character ®

Tags: batch-file, special-characters

I am making a batch file to copy some directories and subdirectories to a safe place (backup purposes). But if the path contains special characters like ® the script does not work.

```
:: Call Of Duty® 2
xcopy "F:\Archivos de Programa\Call Of Duty® 2\main\players" "D:\BackUp\savegames\Call Of Duty® 2\main\players\" /E /F /Y
```

In console the ® shows up as « , so a "not found" exception shows up.

I have tried using UTF-8 and ANSI codification but none of those worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it will work if you also change the code-page of the console to 65001, which is "kind of" a UTF-8 codepage. To do this you must add a command to your batch-file:

```
:: Call Of Duty® 2
chcp 65001
xcopy "F:\Archivos de Programa\Call Of Duty® 2\main\players" ^
    "D:\BackUp\savegames\Call Of Duty® 2\main\players\" /E /F /Y
```

For more information on 65001 read: [Is codepage 65001 and utf-8 the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/) or google [65001+"UTF-8"](https://www.google.com/search?q=65001%20%22UTF-8%22)

Comment: it worked, although the console was not able to show the files that it was copying. Thanks!

Comment: You could also change the font of your console to Consolas or Lucida Console, then it also show the ® character (I prefer Lucida Console 14 ☺).