# sqlcmd utility not showing greek letters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, character-encoding, sqlcmd

First of all I am using SQL Server 9.00.4035.00 which is SQL Server 2005 SP3.

I am using the below command to fetch the results from a view which fetches rows from a table which includes columns with either english or greek characters.

```
sqlcmd -W -S SERVER_NAME -d DATABASE_NAME -U USER_NAME -P PASSWORD -s "|" -Q "set nocount on; set ansi_warnings off;SELECT * from DATABASE.VIEW;"
```

This command returns rows with english characters ok, but when it comes to greek characters I only get ??????

For example instead of

```
1110|20160907|ΓΙΩΡΓΟΣ
```

I am getting

```
1110|20160907|????????
```

I already tried the -f and -u options but none of them seems to work. Here is how I used them:

650001 is for UTF-8 according with [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing)

```
sqlcmd -W -S SERVER_NAME -d DATABASE_NAME -U USER_NAME -P PASSWORD -f 65001 -s "|" -Q "set nocount on; set ansi_warnings off;SELECT * from DATABASE.TABLE;"
```

1253 is for greek accoring to this [book](https://books.google.com.cy/books?id=spu8G2w6PDIC&pg=PA636&lpg=PA636&dq=sqlcmd%20greek&source=bl&ots=p28RN3ZcbA&sig=1DW-4ofXni_yNReHoQJm-yQc3ec&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjYwIjs1vzOAhUJbBoKHfK_CScQ6AEIPDAF#v=onepage&q=sqlcmd%20greek&f=false)

```
sqlcmd -W -S SERVER_NAME -d DATABASE_NAME -U USER_NAME -P PASSWORD -f 1253 -s "|" -Q "set nocount on; set ansi_warnings off;SELECT * from DATABASE.TABLE;"
```

-u option

```
sqlcmd -W -S SERVER_NAME -d DATABASE_NAME -U USER_NAME -P PASSWORD -u -s "|" -Q "set nocount on; set ansi_warnings off;SELECT * from DATABASE.TABLE;"
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The problem was that I was selecting from a view.

So I had DATABASE.TABLE1 and a view DATABASE.VIEW1 which was selecting from TABLE1

If I was selecting from TABLE1, the data was coming as they should using -f 65001
If I was selecting from VIEW1, the data was coming as ???.

The problem was that in the VIEW1 I was casting the already VARCHAR field to VARCHAR. So for some reason when I was casting the VARCHAR to VARCHAR it was missing the Collation I guess.

Comment: collation shouldn't have been your issue unless you were on a linked server. Unicode should be stored as NVARCHAR instead, or NTEXT for older versions.