# Saving XML in client machine

Tags: xml, vbscript, asp-classic

I have an option in my VBScript page where the user can click and I simply read a XML from a database and then I want to save this XML in his machine.

What I have so far is:

```vb
Dim xml: Set xml = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument.3.0")     
xml.LoadXml(xmlEnvio)
```

Where `xmlEnvio` is a variable that contains a XML in string format.

I tried to figure out how to generate and save this file in the client machine but nothing works so far.

[This](http://www.evagoras.com/2011/02/08/downloading-any-file-using-asp-fso-and-the-adodb-stream-object/) is the closest solution I've found, but it's using `LoadFromFile` and I need to generate the file before.

Does anybody knows an approach for doing this?

Comment: But, are you able to generate it? Does it shows your XML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<%
xmlEnvio="<primoPiatto>Spaghetti</primoPiatto>" 'USED IN MY TEST

Response.AddHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=spaghetti.xml"
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.BinaryWrite(xmlEnvio)
Response.End
%>
```

Comment: Hey @Vixed, it worked. I could download the file but somehow it does not display in the browser.
I can open it with Notepad++ for example, I can see that the xml is valid.
An interesting point is if I open the file with Visual Studio Code, it says that " The file will not be displayed in the editor because it is either binary, very large or uses an unsupported text encoding"

Comment: I've changed the BinaryWrite to Write only and  I can open it in Visual Studio Code.
The only thing now is that accentuation does not show properly , for example :"<NomeEmpresarial>Emitꡃomercio de Pissos e Ceramicas LTDA ME</NomeEmpresarial>"   Emit[] should be Emitê

Comment: Try using **Response.ContentType = "application/xml;charset=UTF-8"**

Comment: I tried, but the invalid character keep being showed

Comment: what I have done (and now everything is working fine) was setting the CodePage 65001 to the Response.
I ended up in this following link aswell:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing

Comment: I really don't know how to help you without some row of code.. sorry.