# Telegram Bot Is Not Working

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I made a telegram bot with python-telegram-bot. I have defined a list of words for the bot and I want to manage the chat bot in the group. That is, if there is a word in the chat that is found in the defined list, the bot will delete it. I added the bot to a group and admin it there. The bot should control the messages sent to the group, and if there is a word in the message that is on the mlist, the bot should delete the message. my codes:

```
# -*- coding: cp1256 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, sys
from telegram.ext import Filters
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler
import re

def delete_method(bot, update):
    if not update.message.text:
        print("it does not contain text")
        return

    mlist=['Hello', 'سلام']

    for i in mlist:
        if re.search(i, update.message.text):
            bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id,message_id=update.message.message_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_method))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Can you give us information why it does not work? What kind of errors are returned?

Comment: did u turn off privacy mode for that bot

Comment: @SmartManoj ;no

Comment: @91DarioDev; The bot should delete messages while sending the Persian messages in the mlist to the group, but it will not do this, but if the messages in the mlist are in Latin and will be sent to the group, messages will be deleted. .
There is no error at all

Comment: edit a my codes.

Comment: Look at the messages in the mlist, when the bot sends Hello to the group, it delete it, but when the سلام sends to the group it does not delete the bot.

Comment: I wonder if this is an issue with how the word is being encoded, due to being non-latin characters rather than the actual logic of bot.

Comment: @91DarioDev help me

Answer (score 0):

```
# -*- coding: utf8 -*-
#!python2
import time
import json 
import requests
#TOKEN = XXXXXX
URL = "https://api.telegram.org/bot{}/".format(TOKEN)

def get_updates(offset=None):
    url = URL + "getUpdates?timeout=100"
    if offset:url += "&offset={}".format(offset)
    return requests.get(url).json()


def get_last_update_id(updates):
    update_ids = []
    for update in updates["result"]:
        update_ids.append(int(update["update_id"]))
    return max(update_ids)

def delete_message(message_id, chat_id,msg):
    mlist=['Hello', 'سلام']
    url=URL + "deleteMessage?message_id={}&chat_id={}".format(message_id, chat_id)
    for i in mlist:
        if i in msg:request.get(url)

def echo_all(updates):
    for update in updates["result"]:
        cid = update["message"]["chat"]["id"]
        msg = update["message"].get("text")
        mid = update["message"].get("message_id")
        if msg:delete_message(mid,cid,msg)

def main():
    last_update_id = None
    while True:
        try:
            updates = get_updates(last_update_id)           
            z=updates.get("result")
            if z and len(z) > 0:
                last_update_id = get_last_update_id(updates) + 1
                echo_all(updates)
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ;The bot will not delete سلام when it is sent to the group, but it will be delete when a is sent

Comment: @SmartManojWhen the greetings are sent to the group, the robot does not delete it, and this gives the error: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd8 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Whats ur OS? change shebang if windows else change encoding

Comment: @SmartsManoj windows7 and Python 2.7

Comment: @Sajjad Check now

Comment: @SmartManojError:Unkonwn encoding cp65001.Saving as UTF-8

Comment: @Sajjad [Both](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629454/5033247) are same.
Check [this](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/) also

Comment: Please don't post reserved data such as bot tokens.

Comment: @MatteoItalia No problem.. Itz just a temporary bot..But even if edited it is in revisions.