# I built a telegram bot with Python-Telegram-Bot;But do not work

Tags: python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

I built a telegram bot with Python-Telegram-Bot.I added the bot to a group and got the bot in the admin group.I have defined a list(mlist) for the bot and put it in a list of words.The bot should check the messages the users send to the group.And if users send a message to the group in which the words defined in the list(mlist) are there, the bot must delete it(delete message).

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os, sys
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Fliters
import re


def delete_method(bot, update):
    if not update.message.text:
        print("it does not contain text")
        return

    mlist=['سلام', 'شادي']


   for i in mlist:
        if re.search(i, update.message.text):
            bot.delete_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, message_id=update.message.message_id)

def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
    dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.all, delete_method))

    updater.start_polling()

    updater.idle()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# for exit
# updater.idle()
```

(The bot should delete the messages that are sent to the group and contain the list(mlist) words)
;But the bot does not work, and does not give error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Telegram Bot Is Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45660498/telegram-bot-is-not-working)

Comment: @Sean Explain more

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace the words in `mlist` with english ones and see if it works then. Just to check if that's causing the problem.

EDIT: So it works with english words. The reason is, that Telegram API only supports UTF-8, but Python works with Unicode. Unicode ≠ UTF-8. You have to encode your text with UTF-8. Take a string and add:

`.encode('utf-8')`

Comment: @EndogenWorks with English words

Comment: Here is what happens: Telegram API only supports UTF-8, but Python
works with Unicode. Unicode is not the same as UTF-8. Please see [this post](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/issues/27) from python-telegram-bot library.

Comment: @EndogenWhich line of code do I use for this command?     .encode('utf-8')

Comment: You need to add that to a string. So you have a string `my_string = 'سلام'` and then you do `my_string.encode('utf-8')`. Then you can add that string to the list: `mlist.append(my_string)`

Comment: If that helped you, it would be nice to upvote my post :)