# What is msvc_make.bat?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt, qt-creator, qmake

I have a Qt project setup with microsoft compiler (although I'm using QtCreator) and I noticed it seems to create a file named `msvc_make.bat`, current contents are

```
chcp 65001
"C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" %*
```

What is the purpose of this?

Comment: [Microsoft Doc.: **chcp**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/chcp) - change code page. 65001 represents the code page for UTF-8. [Qt doc.: **jom**](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom): _jom is a clone of nmake_ (Sorry, this was easy to google.)

Comment: _What is the purpose of this?_ I strongly assume the purpose is to ensure that the Windows console is set to UTF-8 before `jom` is called.

Comment: [SO: Is codepage 65001 and utf-8 the same thing?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1629454/7478597)

Answer (score 2):

### Prerequisite knowledge

while creating a makefile for your project using [`qmake`](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qmake-manual.html),either [nmake](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nmake-reference?view=msvc-160) or [jom](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom) is used to execute commands.

### Where is it happening ?

In the source code of Qt creator, this file ( `msvc.bat` ) is created in the [`msvctoolchain.cpp`](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/projectexplorer/msvctoolchain.cpp) file by the function `wrappedMakeCommand()` {on line 1091}

```cpp
static QString wrappedMakeCommand(const QString &command)
{
    const QString wrapperPath = QDir::currentPath() + "/msvc_make.bat";
    QFile wrapper(wrapperPath);
    if (!wrapper.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        return command;
    QTextStream stream(&wrapper);
    stream << "chcp 65001\n";
    stream << "\"" << QDir::toNativeSeparators(command) << "\" %*";

    return wrapperPath;
}
```

which is used by `MsvcToolChain::makeCommand()`{line 1104} function to create the `make command` to build the project.

```cpp
FilePath MsvcToolChain::makeCommand(const Environment &environment) const
{
    bool useJom = ProjectExplorerPlugin::projectExplorerSettings().useJom;
    const QString jom("jom.exe");
    const QString nmake("nmake.exe");
    Utils::FilePath tmp;

    FilePath command;
    if (useJom) {
        tmp = environment.searchInPath(jom,
                                       {Utils::FilePath::fromString(
                                           QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath())});
        if (!tmp.isEmpty())
            command = tmp;
    }

    if (command.isEmpty()) {
        tmp = environment.searchInPath(nmake);
        if (!tmp.isEmpty())
            command = tmp;
    }

    if (command.isEmpty())
        command = FilePath::fromString(useJom ? jom : nmake);

    if (environment.hasKey("VSLANG"))
        return FilePath::fromString(wrappedMakeCommand(command.toString()));

    return command;
}
```

when you look closely in the source code of this function, you will notice that it is just searching for the the required executable (`jom.exe` or `nmake.exe`)

after that, `wrappedMakeCommand()` function is called when environment variable with key "VSLANG" is present ( contains information about the language of the VSCode )

in the function `wrappedMakeCommand()` , developers used a batch file ( `MSVC_make.bat` ) to add another command `chcp 65001` before executing the make file which enables the UTF-8 encoding to understand symbols from different languages just in case the system is running in another language (say Japanese).

#### Disclaimer:

all this information is my interpretation of why this file exists (from the knowledge gained from the source code of qt creator) and I am not 100% sure if this is the correct reason or not, but it made sense to me so answered here.

in case of any correction then do let me know via comments.

#### Sources and useful links :-

1. [Source code of Qt creator](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator) ( via github )
2. [source code of msvctoolchains.cpp](https://github.com/qt-creator/qt-creator/blob/master/src/plugins/projectexplorer/msvctoolchain.cpp) ( where the file is created )
3. [What is jom ?](https://wiki.qt.io/Jom)
4. [about chcp](https://ss64.com/nt/chcp.html)
5. [about qmake](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmake-manual.html)