# Why does SQL not have support for codepage 65001 but has support for 1208?

Tags: sql, db2-luw

I'm trying to add some data using SQL which is using 65001, but looks like this codepage is not supported. However, codepage 1208 is, but these are the same. Is there a reason 1208 was supported but 65001 was left out?

Comment: This is heavily dependent on the specific database you are using. Please specify the database name and version. Please also include the default encoding of the database and schema.

Comment: @TheImpaler we are using DB2 v1155 for this, in window server 2012, on unicode.

Comment: Does it perhaps call it utf-8 instead of 65001?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1629437/is-codepage-65001-and-utf-8-the-same-thing