# UNICODE doesn't work -> "????" (visual c++ 2015)

Tags: c++, unicode, visual-studio-2015, messagebox, windows-1252

I want to use UNICODE in visual C++ 2015 but it doesn't work so I tried a [simple tutorial](https://learnwinapi.wordpress.com/2011/12/13/lesson-2-the-api-is-based-on-unicode/). Here is the code:

```
#undef  UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#undef  STRICT
#define STRICT
#include <windows.h>

int main()
{
    DWORD const infoboxOptions  = MB_OK | MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_SETFOREGROUND;

    char const* const       narrowText  = "It's a 日本国 кошка, LOL!";
    wchar_t const* const    wideText    = L"It's a 日本国 кошка, LOL!";

    MessageBox( 0, wideText, L"Unicode (wide) text:", infoboxOptions );
    MessageBoxA( 0, narrowText, "ANSI (narrow) text:", infoboxOptions );
}
```

It doesn't work either. Both message boxes show "????" instead of special characters.

I even tried putting wWinMainCRTStartup for the entry point, defining _UNICODE in addition to UNICODE, but nothing works.

Maybe it is because that example is not adapted to visual c++ 2015?

Comment: Unable to reproduce.

Comment: What about source-file encoding? Try `UTF-8`

Comment: When I attempt to reproduce this in Visual Studio 2013, it warns me that it can't save the file and offers to save it as Unicode; I select UTF-8 with signature instead. Then it gives me warnings on the line creating the `char` constant but not the `wchar_t` constant. The `MessageBox` works for me but the `MessageBoxA` doesn't, exactly as I'd expect.

Comment: PcAF may have it nailed. If I deliberately bork the encoding I *can* reproduce.

Comment: Thx. How do I set source-file encoding to UTF-8?

Comment: I have "Auto-detect UTF-8 encoding without signature" already ticked off

Comment: The wide-char version of `MessageBoxA` is `MessageBoxW`, not `MessageBox`. `MessageBox` is a macro.

Comment: @Havenard: When `UNICODE` is #defined before `windows.h` is #included, `MessageBox` is the same as `MessageBoxW`

Answer (score 0):

The solution is in this another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5425754/6591414): on the cpp file, Save As... and select "Save With Encoding..." and selecting "UTF-8 without signature"

Comment: On Windows you might find it better to save UTF-8 *with* signature. You're more likely to get consistent operation within Visual Studio and other Windows utilities. Without signature is better when you're passing the file to non-Windows systems.