# VS 2017 .cpp opens incorrectly in other compilers

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dev-c++

Having issues opening a .cpp created in Visual studio in other compilers. My instructor relies on everything but visual studio, and gets garbage when opening a visual studio created cpp file.

image of visual studio created c++ file in Dev-Cpp:

[image: image of visual studio created c++ file in Dev-Cpp]

Comment: how is this file encoded? have you opened it with notepad++ to see if it works okay? see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file

Answer (score 0):

You should check the character encoding of the .cpp file, if you used Visual Studio to create it, it may be UTF-8 with the byte order mark (BOM) sequence to the beginning of the file.
You may use a binary|hexadecimal file viewer to see if the file starts with BOM sequence.

In Visual Studio, if you want to save a file with other encodings select `Save as` and extend the save button in file dialog and select `Save with encoding`.
If you want to remove this setting permanently just open File menu and select `Advanced save options` and there you should select `UTF-8 without signature`.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418557/how-can-i-make-visual-studio-save-all-files-as-utf-8-without-signature-on-projec) and also [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5406172/utf-8-without-bom) for more information and details or alternative solutions.