# convert all C# files to utf-8 encoding

Tags: c#

I need utf-8 encoding for my web page so i am thinking about converting all *.cs and *.aspx files to utf-8. Is that smart idea or is better to convert just *.aspx files.

Now i have problems with čžćšđ

Comment: Where are the troublesome characters coming from? Your aspx or cs files?

Comment: Answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279673/save-all-files-in-visual-studio-project-as-utf-8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only files you need to encode are your ASPX files. If you're using master pages in your project, just specify the encoding there, and it will carry through to all pages using that master page.