# C# String.Format() returns bad characters

Tags: c#, .net, string, unicode, string-formatting

I get very strange behaviour of string.Format. I form message like this:

```
protected override string GetMessageText(ManualEventFact reason)
        {
            var messageText = string.Format("Диспетчер закрыл событие {0}(\"{1}\")",reason.EventTemplate.DisplayName, reason.Text);
            return messageText;
        }
```

The letters in beginning are in Russian. But then, in calling method, i get this string: `Äèñïåò÷åð çàêðûë ñîáûòèå Тревога("Тревога на объекте с точки зрения диспетчера")`. This seems like string.Format returned non-unicode characters for the hard-coded words. How can i deal with this problem? 
P.S. I also faced this in another parts of my app.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably the problem in in the encoding of the source file... If you are using Visual Studio, open the cs file, then go to `File`->`Save (your cs) As`, then near the `Save` Button, click on the small arrow, `Save With Encoding`, and for the `Encoding` select `Unicode (UTF-8 with signature) - Codepage 65001`.

Comment: Oh, this worked! Thanks a lot, but is there any way to force VS to save all cs files with UTF encoding? I don't want to go through all files and check if they are saved correctly...

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy If you create a cs file inside the Visual Studio, it should be UTF-8 by default... This clearly excludes files you wrote with another text-editor and then "included" in your project. If you have a bunch of files and you aren't sure of their encoding, I don't think there is a way *in Visual Studio* to massively change their encodings...

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy There was [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/279673/613130), but I would be very aware of what could happen... If a file isn't encoded in UTF8/Unicode, its encoding isn't "clear" or "implicit", so conversion could "lose" data.

Comment: Hm, anyway, it's worst a try. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: @AlexVoskresenskiy First backup your sorce files! :-)