# Visual Studio GlobalSuppression.cs file and UTF-16

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unicode, code-analysis, utf-16

It seems that Visual Studio 2015 saves the `GlobalSuppression.cs` file using a UTF-16 encoding. This is annoying when using SVN as it perceives that a UTF-16 file is a binary file.

Questions:

- Using Visual Studio, is it possible to save `GlobalSuppression.cs` with a UTF-8 encoding?
- Alternatively, can someone provide a location where I can find the template that this file is based on (if one exists)? Note that I can't find a template in `Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates`.

Comment: It is an auto-generated file that is created when you suppress code analysis warnings, nothing to do with templates.  [Read this](https://rhubbarb.wordpress.com/2012/04/28/svn-unicode/).

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant . This answers the second point of the question. Regarding the link you shared, our solution is to simply remove the 'application/octet-stream' mimi type from the list of svn properties. However, i'm getting the feeling that it won't be possible to automatically change the encoding. Many thanks - Ahmad

Answer (score 0):

To change the encoding of the file into UTF-8 follow following steps. I have tried in VS 2017.

1. Open the file in Visual Studio
2. Select File Option From menu and Select "Save {Your File Name} AS"
   option.
3. Select Advance Save Option
4. Select your Encoding and save the file.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CM7GF.png)