# SonarQube encoding mismatch with .cs source file issue

Tags: c#, encoding, sonarqube

I am running SonarQube 5.6 version and I am trying to integrate .NET application with Sonar. After running sonar-runner, I am getting this warning message

*Encoding detected by Roslyn and encoding used by SonarQu
be do not match for file xxx. SonarQube encoding is 'windows-1252', Roslyn encoding is 'UTF-8'. File will be skipped.*

This is resulting in 0 analysis as all files are getting skipped. One way to make it work is by changing .cs file encoding from Visual Studio one-by-one to windows-1252. This is not feasible as I have big projects with over 1000 files.

Is there any way we can change the encoding for SonarQube? or is there any other way to resolve this.

Comment: We have the same issue. Is there a way to set a different encoding for SonarQube or Roslyn so they are in sync? It is preventing our project from generating any meaningful analysis result so it is a show-stopper to us.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible currently to change the encoding. However, you can easily change the encoding of all your files by following the suggestion here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/850751/1410281

```cs
foreach (var f in new DirectoryInfo(@"...").GetFiles("*.cs", SearchOption.AllDirectories)) {
  string s = File.ReadAllText(f.FullName);
  File.WriteAllText (f.FullName, s, Encoding.UTF8);
}
```

Comment: Thats a work around but it may get some issues in TFS while file compare or merge.  Not sure of this. Ideally there has to be a way to change SonarQube encoding for a project.

Comment: You're right, there should be a way, and I'm sure that SonarSource is working on this issue (see `DEFAULT-PROJECT-ENCODING` branch in [Scanner for MsBuild](https://github.com/SonarSource-VisualStudio/sonar-scanner-msbuild)), but right now UTF-8 is hardcoded.